# Android app not receiving data from servlet

Tags: java, android, servlets

This project has a number (433) saved in a database, which is accessed through a servlet and then should be sent to the Android app. Before I added AsyncTask the app would sometimes retrieve the data (should be 433) from the servlet and sometimes not. Upon clicking the homePage button, the mainActivity screen should appear and display the data. I added AsyncTask hoping it would work consistently, but now all I get is the text "Light Data= " but no data (should say "Light Data= 433). The servlet connects to the database fine, so I know the issue lies within the app. I'd really appreciate code that relates to my project, thankyou.

HomePage:

```
package com.example.clearlight;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;


public class HomePage extends Activity {

    private Button ScheduleBtn;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.homepage);

         ScheduleBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_btn);

        ScheduleBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub


                Intent myIntent = new Intent(HomePage.this, MainActivity.class);
                HomePage.this.startActivity(myIntent);

            }
        });
    }   

}
```

MainActivity:

```
package com.example.clearlight;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.net.URL;

import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;

import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    TextView txt;

    @Override
      public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        
        
        setContentView(R.layout.relative);
               
        
        class LongOperation extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
             
            @Override
            protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
           
            String result=null;
            URL url = null;
 
            DefaultHttpClient httpclient = null;
 
            try {
 
            String registrationUrl = "http://10.0.2.2/SensorInfo/GetLightData?sensor=light";
            url = new URL(registrationUrl);
 
            HttpGet getRequest = new HttpGet(registrationUrl);
            ResponseHandler<String> handler = new BasicResponseHandler();
            httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            // request data from server
            result = httpclient.execute(getRequest, handler);
            Log.d("MyApp", "Data from server is "+ result);
             }
            catch (Exception ex) {Log.e("error",ex.toString());
            ex.printStackTrace();
              }
            return result;
            }
 
            @Override
            protected void onPostExecute(String result)
            {              
              TextView text1 = (TextView)MainActivity.this.findViewById(R.id.text);
 
            //Sets the new text to TextView (runtime click event)//*******
            text1.setText("Light Data= " + result);
 
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Light Data:" + result, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); //MESSAGE BOX
              
            }
 
        }
 
 }
}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.clearlight"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="10"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            
        </activity>
         <activity
            android:name="com.example.clearlight.HomePage"
            android:label="@string/homepage" 
            android:parentActivityName="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" >

            <!-- Moved the intent filter to HomePage -->
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="com.example.clearlight.MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Logcat:

> 03-20 01:08:20.433: D/Launcher.Model(418): Reload apps on config change. curr_mcc:310 prevmcc:0 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks. 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:137) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.database.CursorWindow.(CursorWindow.java:41) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:681) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.database.CursorWindow$1.createFromParcel(CursorWindow.java:679) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor.readFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:75) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:34) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at android.database.BulkCursorDescriptor$1.createFromParcel(BulkCursorDescriptor.java:30) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at android.content.ContentProviderProxy.query(ContentProviderNative.java:369) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:370) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:301) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:68) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:56) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 03-20 01:08:20.473: E/StrictMode(401):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 03-20 01:08:20.484: D/Launcher.Model(418): going to save icon bitmap for info=ShortcutInfo(title=Settingsintent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.settings/.Settings }id=6 type=0 container=-100 screen=3 cellX=2 cellY=3 spanX=1 spanY=1 isGesture=false dropPos=null) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401): A resource was acquired at attached stack trace but never released. See java.io.Closeable for information on avoiding resource leaks. 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401): java.lang.Throwable: Explicit termination method 'close' not called 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):     at dalvik.system.CloseGuard.open(CloseGuard.java:184) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):    at android.content.ContentResolver$CursorWrapperInner.(ContentResolver.java:1835) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):  at android.content.ContentResolver.query(ContentResolver.java:392) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:65) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.content.CursorLoader.loadInBackground(CursorLoader.java:43) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):   at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader.onLoadInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:301) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:68) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):  at android.content.AsyncTaskLoader$LoadTask.doInBackground(AsyncTaskLoader.java:56) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569) 03-20 01:08:20.534: E/StrictMode(401):   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856) 03-20 01:08:20.534: W/CursorWrapperInner(401): Cursor finalized without prior close() 03-20 01:08:20.563: W/CursorWrapperInner(401): Cursor finalized without prior close() 03-20 01:08:20.614: D/AlertService(401): No fired or scheduled alerts 03-20 01:08:20.704: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_CONCURRENT freed 328K, 5% free 10193K/10631K, paused 17ms+7ms, total 95ms 03-20 01:08:20.723: D/Launcher.Model(418): going to save icon bitmap for info=ShortcutInfo(title=Messagingintent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.mms/.ui.ConversationList }id=12 type=0 container=-101 screen=3 cellX=3 cellY=0 spanX=1 spanY=1 isGesture=false dropPos=null) 03-20 01:08:20.833: D/Launcher.Model(418): going to save icon bitmap for info=ShortcutInfo(title=Peopleintent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.contacts/.activities.PeopleActivity }id=10 type=0 container=-101 screen=1 cellX=1 cellY=0 spanX=1 spanY=1 isGesture=false dropPos=null) 03-20 01:08:20.893: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms 03-20 01:08:21.083: D/dalvikvm(163): GC_EXPLICIT freed 222K, 47% free 10043K/18887K, paused 25ms+10ms, total 187ms 03-20 01:08:21.113: D/Launcher.Model(418): going to save icon bitmap for info=ShortcutInfo(title=Phoneintent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.contacts/.activities.DialtactsActivity }id=8 type=0 container=-101 screen=0 cellX=0 cellY=0 spanX=1 spanY=1 isGesture=false dropPos=null) 03-20 01:08:21.203: D/Launcher.Model(418): going to save icon bitmap for info=ShortcutInfo(title=Browserintent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.browser/.BrowserActivity }id=14 type=0 container=-101 screen=4 cellX=4 cellY=0 spanX=1 spanY=1 isGesture=false dropPos=null) 03-20 01:08:21.293: D/Launcher.Model(418): going to save icon bitmap for info=ShortcutInfo(title=Cameraintent=Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10200000 cmp=com.android.camera/.Camera }id=4 type=0 container=-100 screen=2 cellX=0 cellY=3 spanX=1 spanY=1 isGesture=false dropPos=null) 03-20 01:08:21.713: I/PackageManager(163): Running dexopt on: com.example.clearlight 03-20 01:08:22.373: D/EmailProvider(570): Creating EmailProviderBody database 03-20 01:08:22.623: D/dalvikvm(375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 359K, 6% free 8370K/8839K, paused 17ms+45ms, total 174ms 03-20 01:08:22.943: D/EmailProvider(570): Creating EmailProvider database 03-20 01:08:23.623: D/dalvikvm(637): DexOpt: load 310ms, verify+opt 1126ms, 788740 bytes 03-20 01:08:23.833: D/EmailProvider(570): fromDatabase accounts: 0 03-20 01:08:23.844: D/EmailProvider(570): ending toDatabase transaction; copyCount = 0 03-20 01:08:23.873: D/EmailProvider(570): ending fromDatabase transaction; copyCount = 0 03-20 01:08:24.653: I/Email(570): Onetime initialization: completed. 03-20 01:08:24.964: D/dalvikvm(163): GC_CONCURRENT freed 452K, 47% free 10034K/18887K, paused 33ms+15ms, total 129ms 03-20 01:08:24.964: D/PackageManager(163): New package installed in /data/app/com.example.clearlight-1.apk 03-20 01:08:25.804: I/ActivityManager(163): Force stopping package com.example.clearlight uid=10037 03-20 01:08:25.954: W/ResourceType(418): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f0d0017 which is invalid or in a cycle. 03-20 01:08:25.954: W/ResourceType(418): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f0d0017 which is invalid or in a cycle. 03-20 01:08:25.954: W/ResourceType(418): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f0d0017 which is invalid or in a cycle. 03-20 01:08:25.954: W/ResourceType(418): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f0d0017 which is invalid or in a cycle. 03-20 01:08:25.954: W/ResourceType(418): Attempt to retrieve bag 0x7f0d0017 which is invalid or in a cycle. 03-20 01:08:26.294: D/AlertService(401): 0 Action = android.intent.action.PROVIDER_CHANGED 03-20 01:08:26.294: D/AlertService(401): Beginning updateAlertNotification 03-20 01:08:26.424: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms 03-20 01:08:26.554: I/AccountTypeManager(501): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 78ms(wall) 5ms(cpu) 03-20 01:08:26.604: I/Choreographer(418): Skipped 1623 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 03-20 01:08:26.735: D/PackageManager(163): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged 03-20 01:08:26.754: I/InputReader(163): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010 03-20 01:08:26.764: D/PackageManager(163): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged 03-20 01:08:26.764: D/BackupManagerService(163): Received broadcast Intent { act=android.intent.action.PACKAGE_ADDED dat=package:com.example.clearlight flg=0x8000010 (has extras) } 03-20 01:08:26.984: D/gralloc_goldfish(418): Emulator without GPU emulation detected. 03-20 01:08:26.994: V/BackupManagerService(163): addPackageParticipantsLocked: #1 03-20 01:08:27.124: W/InputMethodManagerService(163): Found no subtypes in a system IME: com.android.inputmethod.pinyin 03-20 01:08:27.205: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 414K, 5% free 10364K/10887K, paused 55ms, total 104ms 03-20 01:08:27.224: I/dalvikvm-heap(418): Grow heap (frag case) to 11.564MB for 1463056-byte allocation 03-20 01:08:27.334: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 30K, 5% free 11763K/12359K, paused 104ms, total 104ms 03-20 01:08:27.434: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 11763K/12359K, paused 17ms+21ms, total 106ms 03-20 01:08:27.564: D/dalvikvm(521): GC_CONCURRENT freed 225K, 4% free 8180K/8455K, paused 955ms+42ms, total 2035ms 03-20 01:08:27.694: E/SQLiteLog(521): (1) no such table: files 03-20 01:08:27.804: D/dalvikvm(163): GC_EXPLICIT freed 548K, 47% free 10010K/18887K, paused 1038ms+24ms, total 1380ms 03-20 01:08:27.804: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 198ms 03-20 01:08:27.814: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 511ms 03-20 01:08:27.814: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 444ms 03-20 01:08:27.824: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 415ms 03-20 01:08:27.834: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 413ms 03-20 01:08:27.834: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 372ms 03-20 01:08:27.834: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 372ms 03-20 01:08:27.834: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 369ms 03-20 01:08:27.844: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 371ms 03-20 01:08:27.844: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 369ms 03-20 01:08:27.844: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 327ms 03-20 01:08:27.844: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 324ms 03-20 01:08:27.944: D/ExchangeService(587): !!! EAS ExchangeService, onStartCommand, startingUp = true, running = false 03-20 01:08:27.944: D/dalvikvm(36): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms 03-20 01:08:27.964: I/ActivityManager(163): Start proc com.svox.pico for broadcast com.svox.pico/.VoiceDataInstallerReceiver: pid=649 uid=10015 gids={1015, 1028} 03-20 01:08:28.074: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed 37K, 4% free 7964K/8259K, paused 6ms+8ms, total 132ms 03-20 01:08:28.084: D/dalvikvm(36): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms 03-20 01:08:28.174: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2K, 5% free 11765K/12359K, paused 312ms, total 346ms 03-20 01:08:28.204: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 7964K/8259K, paused 24ms+5ms, total 121ms 03-20 01:08:28.204: I/dalvikvm-heap(418): Grow heap (frag case) to 12.932MB for 1463056-byte allocation 03-20 01:08:28.214: D/dalvikvm(36): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 0ms 03-20 01:08:28.344: E/Trace(649): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 03-20 01:08:28.364: D/dalvikvm(36): GC_EXPLICIT freed <1K, 4% free 7964K/8259K, paused 15ms+5ms, total 145ms 03-20 01:08:28.454: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_CONCURRENT freed <1K, 5% free 13193K/13831K, paused 31ms+8ms, total 243ms 03-20 01:08:28.454: D/dalvikvm(418): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 195ms 03-20 01:08:28.484: I/ActivityThread(649): Pub com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider: com.svox.pico.providers.SettingsProvider 03-20 01:08:28.615: D/dalvikvm(163): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 1152ms 03-20 01:08:28.714: I/ActivityManager(163): Displayed com.android.launcher/com.android.launcher2.Launcher: +26s665ms (total
> +37s591ms) 03-20 01:08:28.787: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009002_00000000 [127 ipp] (149 ins) at [0x4124a4b8:0x4124a70c] in 917426 ns 03-20 01:08:29.199: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03010104_00008002_00000000 [ 89 ipp] (110 ins) at [0x4124a710:0x4124a8c8] in 809441 ns 03-20 01:08:29.394: D/dalvikvm(277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 9816K, 53% free 9024K/18887K, paused 702ms, total 748ms 03-20 01:08:29.414: I/dalvikvm-heap(277): Grow heap (frag case) to 15.888MB for 7372816-byte allocation 03-20 01:08:29.584: D/dalvikvm(277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 132K, 15% free 16091K/18887K, paused 50ms+18ms, total 176ms 03-20 01:08:29.864: D/dalvikvm(277): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed <1K, 15% free 16091K/18887K, paused 47ms, total 47ms 03-20 01:08:29.894: I/dalvikvm-heap(277): Grow heap (frag case) to 18.688MB for 3072016-byte allocation 03-20 01:08:30.024: D/dalvikvm(277): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 13% free 19091K/21895K, paused 20ms+19ms, total 126ms 03-20 01:08:30.024: D/dalvikvm(277): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 107ms 03-20 01:08:30.504: D/AndroidRuntime(250): Shutting down VM 03-20 01:08:30.524: D/dalvikvm(250): GC_CONCURRENT freed 97K, 78% free 453K/2048K, paused 1ms+2ms, total 15ms 03-20 01:08:30.524: D/jdwp(250): Got wake-up signal, bailing out of select 03-20 01:08:30.524: D/dalvikvm(250): Debugger has detached; object registry had 1 entries 03-20 01:08:30.534: I/AndroidRuntime(250): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed 03-20 01:08:30.794: I/InputReader(163): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010 03-20 01:08:30.844: D/PackageManager(163): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged 03-20 01:08:30.864: I/InputReader(163): Reconfiguring input devices.  changes=0x00000010 03-20 01:08:30.894: D/PackageManager(163): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged 03-20 01:08:31.024: D/PackageManager(163): generateServicesMap(android.accounts.AccountAuthenticator): 2 services unchanged 03-20 01:08:31.064: D/PackageManager(163): generateServicesMap(android.content.SyncAdapter): 4 services unchanged 03-20 01:08:31.264: I/AccountTypeManager(501): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 30ms(wall) 6ms(cpu) 03-20 01:08:31.294: I/AccountTypeManager(501): Loaded meta-data for 1 account types, 0 accounts in 24ms(wall) 7ms(cpu) 03-20 01:08:31.564: D/AndroidRuntime(668): >>>>>> AndroidRuntime START com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit <<<<<< 03-20 01:08:31.564: D/AndroidRuntime(668): CheckJNI is ON 03-20 01:08:31.644: D/dalvikvm(668): Trying to load lib libjavacore.so 0x0 03-20 01:08:31.664: D/dalvikvm(668): Added shared lib libjavacore.so 0x0 03-20 01:08:31.734: D/dalvikvm(668): Trying to load lib libnativehelper.so 0x0 03-20 01:08:31.734: D/dalvikvm(668): Added shared lib libnativehelper.so 0x0 03-20 01:08:31.904: D/dalvikvm(163): GC_CONCURRENT freed 404K, 48% free 10005K/18887K, paused 116ms+20ms, total 388ms 03-20 01:08:32.254: D/dalvikvm(501): GC_CONCURRENT freed 203K, 4% free 8205K/8519K, paused 98ms+21ms, total 963ms 03-20 01:08:32.564: D/AlertService(401): No fired or scheduled alerts 03-20 01:08:32.834: D/dalvikvm(469): GC_CONCURRENT freed 232K, 4% free 8181K/8519K, paused 90ms+7ms, total 540ms 03-20 01:08:33.074: I/Choreographer(418): Skipped 1563 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 03-20 01:08:33.094: D/AndroidRuntime(668): Calling main entry com.android.commands.am.Am 03-20 01:08:33.164: I/ActivityManager(163): START {act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.example.clearlight/.HomePage u=0} from pid 668 03-20 01:08:33.214: D/PermissionCache(35): checking android.permission.READ_FRAME_BUFFER for uid=1000 => granted (1103 us) 03-20 01:08:33.224: W/WindowManager(163): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21005 03-20 01:08:33.234: D/AndroidRuntime(668): Shutting down VM 03-20 01:08:33.274: D/dalvikvm(668): GC_CONCURRENT freed 98K, 77% free 483K/2048K, paused 2ms+3ms, total 32ms 03-20 01:08:33.284: I/AndroidRuntime(668): NOTE: attach of thread 'Binder_3' failed 03-20 01:08:33.404: I/ContactDirectoryManager(375): deleted 0 stale rows which don't have any relevant directory 03-20 01:08:33.604: D/dalvikvm(682): Not late-enabling CheckJNI (already on) 03-20 01:08:33.635: I/ActivityManager(163): Start proc com.example.clearlight for activity com.example.clearlight/.HomePage: pid=682 uid=10037 gids={3003, 1028} 03-20 01:08:34.093: E/Trace(682): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 03-20 01:08:34.314: I/ARMAssembler(35): generated scanline__00000077:03515104_00009001_00000000 [131 ipp] (153 ins) at [0x4124a8d0:0x4124ab34] in 736260 ns 03-20 01:08:34.754: D/gralloc_goldfish(682): Emulator without GPU emulation detected. 03-20 01:08:34.824: I/ActivityManager(163): Displayed com.example.clearlight/.HomePage: +1s253ms 03-20 01:08:35.484: I/ContactDirectoryManager(375): Discovered 0 contact directories in 7915ms 03-20 01:08:35.484: I/Launcher(418): setLoadOnResume 03-20 01:08:35.564: I/Launcher(418): setLoadOnResume 03-20 01:08:35.615: W/RecognitionManagerService(163): no available voice recognition services found 03-20 01:08:35.634: I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(375): Switching to locale en_US 03-20 01:08:35.785: D/dalvikvm(418): GREF has increased to 201 03-20 01:08:35.804: I/Launcher(418): setLoadOnResume 03-20 01:08:35.804: I/Launcher(418): setLoadOnResume 03-20 01:08:35.983: W/ActivityManager(163): Permission denied: checkComponentPermission() owningUid=1000 03-20 01:08:35.983: W/BroadcastQueue(163): Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE_OPTIONS flg=0x10 cmp=com.android.settings/.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider (has extras) } from android (pid=418, uid=10014) is not exported from uid 1000 due to receiver com.android.settings/com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider 03-20 01:08:36.003: I/Launcher(418): setLoadOnResume 03-20 01:08:36.074: E/WVMExtractor(38): Failed to open libwvm.so 03-20 01:08:36.213: D/dalvikvm(418): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1906K, 14% free 12996K/15047K, paused 36ms+14ms, total 145ms 03-20 01:08:36.613: I/ActivityManager(163): Start proc com.android.quicksearchbox for broadcast com.android.quicksearchbox/.CorporaUpdateReceiver: pid=700 uid=10006 gids={3003, 1028} 03-20 01:08:36.773: E/Trace(700): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2) 03-20 01:08:36.903: I/ActivityThread(700): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.google: com.android.quicksearchbox.google.GoogleSuggestionProvider 03-20 01:08:36.993: I/ActivityThread(700): Pub com.android.quicksearchbox.shortcuts: com.android.quicksearchbox.ShortcutsProvider 03-20 01:08:37.363: I/Choreographer(418): Skipped 126 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. 03-20 01:08:37.373: E/WVMExtractor(38): Failed to open libwvm.so 03-20 01:08:38.434: I/Launcher(418): setLoadOnResume 03-20 01:08:38.454: I/Launcher(418): setLoadOnResume 03-20 01:08:38.543: E/WVMExtractor(38): Failed to open libwvm.so 03-20 01:08:38.603: E/MetadataRetrieverClient(38): failed to extract an album art 03-20 01:08:39.003: D/dalvikvm(375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 387K, 6% free 8414K/8903K, paused 31ms+5ms, total 110ms 03-20 01:08:39.263: I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(375): Locale change completed in 3621ms 03-20 01:08:39.263: I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(375): Switching to locale en_US 03-20 01:08:39.763: I/ContactsDatabaseHelper(375): Locale change completed in 501ms 03-20 01:08:39.773: I/ContactsProvider(375): Upgrading aggregation algorithm 03-20 01:08:39.803: I/ContactAggregator(375): Marked all visible contacts for aggregation: 0 raw contacts, 21 ms 03-20 01:08:39.833: I/ContactsProvider(375): Aggregation algorithm upgraded for 0 raw contacts in 59ms 03-20 01:08:40.263: I/ContactsFTS(375): Rebuild contact search index in 340ms, 0 contacts 03-20 01:08:40.533: D/dalvikvm(375): GC_CONCURRENT freed 447K, 7% free 8413K/8967K, paused 75ms+104ms, total 241ms 03-20 01:08:41.633: I/ActivityManager(163): START {cmp=com.example.clearlight/.MainActivity u=0} from pid 682 03-20 01:08:41.633: W/WindowManager(163): Failure taking screenshot for (246x410) to layer 21010 03-20 01:08:42.063: I/ActivityManager(163): Displayed com.example.clearlight/.MainActivity: +418ms 03-20 01:08:43.843: D/dalvikvm(163): GC_CONCURRENT freed 281K, 47% free 10128K/18887K, paused 123ms+10ms, total 225ms

Comment: What gets logged from Log.d("MyApp", "Data from server is "+ result);

Comment: If you are doing this asynchronously, it could be that you are printing the result before the data is received.

Comment: @Nick - if you are using Eclipse one of the Android-specific views is logcat output.  Everything you log should go there, along with the stack trace if your process crashes.

Comment: Is your LongOperation class declared in OnCreate()? Weird. Where do you instantiate and call it? Why StrinctMode? Please try without.

Comment: I've pasted the logcat @antlersoft, also greenapps I tried without strict mode and it made no difference